# Flutter in_app_purchase 0.3.1+2 Plugin Not Getting Products

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, google-play-console

I've been trying to introduce Billing into my app. I have successfully set everything up in the Google Play Console.

Am using the in_app_purchase 0.3.1+2 to fetch the products, i have just one but it doesn't return anything, I always get an empty [] response.

Below is my code for querying the products. Also my product was created under Managed products in the Google Play Console.

```
List<String> _productIds;
InAppPurchaseConnection _purchaseConnection;

queryProducts() {
  this._productIds = ['my.only.poroduct.id'];
  this._purchaseConnection = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance;

  this._purchaseConnection = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance;
  bool isAvailable = await this._purchaseConnection.isAvailable();
  if (!isAvailable) {
    // handle here
  }
  else {
    List<ProductDetails> productDetails = [];
    this._purchaseConnection = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance;
    ProductDetailsResponse productDetailsResponse = await this._purchaseConnection.queryProductDetails(this._productIds.toSet());
    if (productDetailsResponse.error != null) {
      // handle error
      print('error: ' + productDetailsResponse.error.toString()); // returns no error
      return null;
    }

    if (productDetailsResponse.productDetails.isEmpty) {
      // handle not found
      print('product_details: ' + productDetailsResponse.productDetails.length.toString()); // always zero
      return [];
    }
    else {
      // doesnt even get here
      productDetails = productDetailsResponse.productDetails;
      return productDetails;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what am doing wrong. The app hasn't been published yet, its still pending review. The status of the managed product is Active.

I could really use some help. Thank You.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RahulChauhan no i didnt. What I had to do was use the android.test.purchased for the product id.

Comment: It is working after app is live on play store.

Comment: Ok great @Rahul Chauhan

Comment: Facing same issue, I have released app on close track but getting 0 products in _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_kProductIds.toSet()); inAppPurchase is available nut not getting subscription prdocts, Any luck?  using in_app_purchase: ^3.0.5

Comment: @NidhiDesai it only works when your app is published. What you can do it publish it on the app stores, you can set them as alpha or beta releases so it's closed to the general public.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Already published in close track @marvinralph